# Pasting russian in desktop application

Tags: c++, copy-paste, desktop, cyrillic

I created a simple desktop file editor in Dev C++.

There I can write Russian characters, but when I copy and paste Russian from other programs I see only "?????".

What can I do?

Comment: Usually if you do not have the fonts you will see the "?????"

Comment: So your editor is not supporting unicode as I would guess...

Comment: "setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); 
     SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);"

Comment: What is "Russian characters"? Do you mean Cyrillic?

Comment: @Ziezi uh, presumably he means characters from the [Russian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet), which (at least as ignorant-westerner-me understands it) is one of *several* Cyrillic alphabets. Plenty of things are unclear in this question, but the meaning of the phrase "Russian characters" isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Control Panel -> Regional Settings -> Language -> Additional parameters -> Change Windows interface language : Russian. 
[image]